# Sublime Text 2 shortcut to select a sentence

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

Any keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text 2 to select the string in quotation marks:

```
<input type="text" value="i want to select these texts ..." />
alert("i want to select these texts ...");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the `Selection` menu is an option `Expand Selection to Scope`, which should be what you're looking for, since strings enclosed in quotes are defined as a separate scope in most languages, including the default HTML that comes with ST2.

I tested several languages, including HTML, JavaScript, JSON, Ruby, Perl, and Python, and all except Python selected the quotes along with the text. If you want to change that behavior you'll have to dive into `Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage`, figure out the regexes involved, and transfer them to the `.tmLanguage` file(s) of your language(s) of choice.

Comment: @AGS right, I'm going through the very large `Python.tmLanguage` file to see how it works. **Workaround**: only program in Python :)

Comment: Cool it is!  @AGS, quotation is not a big problem ~~

Answer (score 1):

Try the [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) plugin. Use the command palette command `Select Bracket Content`. I believe that is what you are looking for. If it is, you can create a keymap with the following command (got this from logging the command, but you can also see it by looking through the sublime-commands file)

```
"keys": ["<you choose keys>"],
"command": "bh_key",
"args": {"lines": true, "plugin": {"command": "bh_modules.bracketselect", "type": ["__all__"]}}
```

Comment: do you know enough about `.tmLanguage` regexes to figure out why the scopes in the other languages contain the quotes while Python doesn't?

Comment: I just did a test with python and it appears to select the quotes also, so I'm not sure why you are seeing different behavior. If I had to guess though, I would say that the begin/end patterns aren't set up properly. I would try using the [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) plugin to track down what scopes are being applied, then search for those scopes in the `tmLanguage` file. From there you can see begin/end patterns are being applied.

Comment: I can do that, it's just interpreting the regexes I'm having problems with.

Comment: Oh, I just remembered - I'm using a customized version of facelessuser's [Better Python](https://github.com/facelessuser/sublime-languages/tree/master/Better%20Python) syntax. Maybe I can track him down and ask...